# What is the limit of messages per second using quickblox as my backend?

Tags: quickblox

Also, say I am in a group of 1000 people, and I send a message - does that equal to 1000 messages? As the server needs to send a message to each participant.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the limit for number of messages per second depending on plan here: http://quickblox.com/plans/

As for "does hat equal to 1000 messages?" - it depends on the code (plartform) you are using.

Comment: Is this measured in "messages per second" over all or "messages per second per user"?